# Numpy array operation to shift index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices

I have a very specific situation: I have a long 1-D numpy array (`arr`). I am interested in those elements that are greater than a no. (`n`). So I am using: `idx = np.argwhere(arr > n)` and: `val = arr[idx]` to get the elements and their indices. Now the problem: I am adding an integer offset (`ofs`) to the indices (`idx`) and bringing back the overflowing indices to the front using: `idx = (idx + ofs) % len(arr)` (as if the original array (`arr`) is rolled and again argwhere used). If it is correct till here, what exactly should I use to get the updated `val` (the array that corresponds to the `idx`)? Thanks in advance.

Ex: Let `arr=[2,5,8,4,9]`, `n=4`, so `idx=[1,2,4]` and `val=[5,8,9]`. Now let `ofs=3`, then `idx=[4,5,7]%5=[4,0,2]`. I expect `val=[8,9,5]`.

Comment: For help, it is be better to prepare an example that represent your expected results from the inputs.

Comment: The calculation `idx=[4,5,7]%5=[4,0,2]` contradicts your statement that you want to continue counting from the start of the array when idx+ofs exceeds the length of arr (in this case, the result would be `[9 2 8]`. Which one is it?

Comment: idx values should roll over when idx+ofs exceeds the length of arr (here 5). It is what is expected if the original arr is rolled by ofs first and then argwhere'ed, isn't it?

Comment: It is not clear what you need after you reach to the `[4,0,2]` indices. How these indices must be applied on the array to result `val=[8,9,5]`????

Comment: Explanation and example do not match.

Comment: Yes it might be simple but I am stuck :P

Comment: @michael-szczesny which part, are all example values not consistent?

Comment: Please clear that how that final indices will work on the array to get the expected `val`? step by step. how each index in `[4,0,2]` works?

Comment: @Ali_Sh Imagine the elements in `val` are tied to the `idx`. Once `idx` is updated, it has nothing to do with the `arr`, instead the elements are just permuted by that relation. So how should the one-to-one elements in `val` get rearranged. Nothing to fetch again from `arr` using updated `idx` @Mr. T. I am sorry for lack of explanation skills.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand the aim of this question correctly, but if we want to rearrange `val` with orders in `idx`, it can be done by `np.argsort` as:

```
mask_idx = np.where(arr > n)[0]                 # satisfied indices in arr, where elements are bigger than the specified value
val = arr[mask_idx]                             # satisfied corresponding values
mask_updated_idx = (mask_idx + ofs) % len(arr)  # --> [4 0 2]

idx_sorted = mask_updated_idx.argsort()         # --> [1 2 0]  indices rearranging order array
val = val[idx_sorted]                           # --> [8 9 5]
```